# How to reset a user's password in MySQL 8.0

Tags: mysql, passwords, mysql-8.0

### my problem & details

I want to change a user's password in MySQL8.0, but it seems nearly all the method on the web didn't work.

here's my mysql.user table details:

```
mysql> select user, host from user;
+------------------+-----------+
| user             | host      |
+------------------+-----------+
| Excalibur        | %         |
| yyy              | %         |
| mysql.infoschema | localhost |
| mysql.session    | localhost |
| mysql.sys        | localhost |
| root             | localhost |
+------------------+-----------+
```

### what I have done

I'v tried the command:

```sql
alter user 'yyy'@'%' identified with mysql_native_password by '12345';
```

and received error message:

```sql
ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation ALTER USER failed for 'yyy'@'%'
```

---

I also tried manipulating the mysql.user tables by myself:

```sql
update user set authentication_string=sha1('12345') where user = 'yyy' ;
flush privileges;
```

though it worked, but then **i can't login yyy by (what i supposed to be) password 12345**. then i took a glance of the table and it indeed appeared weird:

```
+------------------+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| user             | host      | authentication_string                                                  |
+------------------+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Excalibur        | %         | $A$005$tE.D2|7^FTRYjmg1APzveuTWyJ1BaO2al1GKvO3UJO6ZlX06jqbNkT5 |
| yyy              | %         | 8cb2237d0679ca88db6464eac60da96345513964                               |
| mysql.infoschema | localhost | $A$005$THISISACOMBINATIONOFINVALIDSALTANDPASSWORDTHATMUSTNEVERBRBEUSED |
| mysql.session    | localhost | $A$005$THISISACOMBINATIONOFINVALIDSALTANDPASSWORDTHATMUSTNEVERBRBEUSED |
...
```

Comment: Have you tried with the FLUSH PRIVILEGES command after changing the password? It's needed in order to pick up the new values

Comment: yes, surely i did. (sorry, i forgot to add it on)

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL 8.0

general user using below command to change the password

```
ALTER USER 'userName'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'New-Password-Here';
```

root user using below command to change the password

P.S check using password with lead "$A$005$" which should be use caching_sha2_password authentication plugin, if no "WITH caching_sha2_password" will not work on root user. if general user
need should be grant the permission.

```
ALTER USER 'userName'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH caching_sha2_password BY 'New-Password-Here';
```

Comment: However, it will still suffered `ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation ALTER USER failed for 'yyy'@'%'`.   And also if i use `sha2('12345', 0)`(or other arg like 224...) replacing `sha1('12345')` in method 2 i've stated above, it won't generate "$A$005" ahead as well (puzzled: how to generate $A$005, should i add it forcely ?)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to mysql_native_password with auth of the user, please remember add
the below to mysqld.cnf which using the mysql_native_password with the default auth.

```
[mysqld]
default_authentication_plugin=mysql_native_password
authentication_policy=mysql_native_password,,
```

the auth of root is auth_socket which check the root with unix root permission. if you use

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH caching_sha2_password BY 'New-Password-Here';
```

It will let root only auth with the password without limit which the unix user.
P.S You can use command to check the auth in the user

```
mysql> select user,host,plugin from mysql.user;
+------------------+-----------+-----------------------+
| user             | host      | plugin                |
+------------------+-----------+-----------------------+
| debian-sys-maint | localhost | caching_sha2_password |
| mysql.infoschema | localhost | caching_sha2_password |
| mysql.session    | localhost | caching_sha2_password |
| mysql.sys        | localhost | caching_sha2_password |
| root             | localhost | auth_socket           |
| www              | localhost | mysql_native_password |
+------------------+-----------+-----------------------+
```